# Capture a request by lua nginx module

Tags: nginx, lua

How to capture a request (ngx.req) in lua nginx module?(depend on method of request).

In lua nginx config, I need to check some conditions before send the request and return the response as normal, how can I do that?

I have used ngx.location.capture, but the method is different with method of ngx.req. I also use ngx.redirect(ngx.req) but it didn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use the return statement to continue the request. `return;`

Comment: Are you sure that you answered you question? And "using return statement" is a method  of "Capture a request by lua nginx module"?